# href заменяет url полностью, а не добавляет в конец

Tags: javascript, github, url, github-pages, href

Есть кнопка с href="/about".

На локалке URL меняется нормально, т.е. содержимое href добавляется в конец.

На github pages URL выглядит так: (http's://ИМЯ.github.io/РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ/), т.е. добавляется еще название репозитория.
По нажатию на кнопку с вышеупомянутым href, URL меняется на (http's://ИМЯ.github.io/about), что влечет проблему с роутингом.

Собственно, как сделать так, чтобы название репозитория оставалось?
пример: (http's://ИМЯ.github.io/РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ/about)

Менять слэш на хэш нельзя, нужно работать именно с pathname а не hash

Comment: Надо сделать `href="about"`, без слэша `/`

Comment: Благодарю, работает

Comment: Сейчас оформлю как ответ, чтобы другим тоже могло помочь.

Comment: Окей, отмечу его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сделать `href="about"`, без слэша `/`.

Так как файловая система GitHub Pages отличается от файловой системы локального сервера (или локальной файловой системы), лучше либо не использовать корневые директории*, либо переписывать код для GitHub Pages, когда вы загружаете его на GitHub Pages.

Но, есть один момент: если вы загружаете сайт в корневую директорию* GitHub Pages (в репозиторий вашего аккаунта `ИМЯ.github.io`), то там можно оставить `/`, потому что там корневая директория будет `ИМЯ.github.io/` без названия репозитория, и при любой ссылке в этом репозитории, всё будет ссылаться на корневой репозиторий, поэтому там можно не убирать `/`.

** директория = папка*.

<sub><sup>*Если вам что-то не нравится, оставьте комментарий, и я улучшу ответ.</sup></sub>